# Firebase "read" rules executing even when no document is found in a query result

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In my Firebase Firestore Rules, I have the following rule for 'courses' collection:

```
rules_version = '2'
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /courses/{courseId} {
      allow read: if resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

The rules works ok if a read a single document using the firebase web client.
But when querying and the result is empty, for instance the following query:

```
const results = await app.firestore().collection('courses')
   .where('userId', '==', 'unexistingUserId').get();
```

then the rules fail, throwing an exception on the client side (Missing or insufficient permissions).

Running locally on the emulator, I found that the problem was that the read rule was being validated against a resource containing the query field, even if with the resource not existing:

[image]

As shown above, the resource.data.userId contains the "unexistingUserId" value.

To solve this, I had to change the rules by adding validations to check if the resource exists:

```
rules_version = '2'
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /courses/{courseId} {
      allow read: if resource==null || resource.data==null || !('id' in resource) || resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

Now when querying for no results, the rule validates ok because the 'id' is not present in the request object:
[image]

So my questions are:

- Is this the expected behavior?
- Shouldn't the rules not even being validated if the query returns nothing?
- Is there a way to change this behavior to avoid adding those checks in all my rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this the expected behavior?

> Shouldn't the rules not even being validated if the query returns nothing?

This is the expected behavior.  What are you are observing is because of the fact that [security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).  Be sure to read and understand that linked documentation.

Queries work differently than single document get().  With a single document get(), the rules system doesn't have to worry about scaling up to match billions of documents, so it's perfectly reasonable to check the contents of the one document to see if it matches.  However, since queries can return 0 or more documents, the rules are considered differently.  They do not simply check each document that would result from a query.  That wouldn't scale at all for very large collections.

Rules work with queries by checking that the filters on the client's query match the constraints in the rule.  If you say that `resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid`, what you are expressing is that users may **only ever try to query for documents where userId equals their own UID**.  They are not allowed to even attempt to match any other document in a query.

The only query that would ever pass this rule would look more like this:

```
const results = await app.firestore()
    .collection('courses')
    .where('userId', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser)
    .get();
```

In this case, the filter:

```
.where('userId', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser)
```

Exactly matches the rule:

```
allow read: if resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid;
```

Any other query would be rejected immediately simply because it's trying to access documents that are known to violate the rule.

Comment: Thank you @Doug, I really had a misconception about the "Rules are not filter", I thought that it meant that the rules would not filter the data (for instance, querying for all docs in a collection, the rules would not force to retrieve just the matching docs), but I thought it would run the query, and then for every doc, validate the rules, and if one doc fails, the whole query fails. But now, thinking about, the firebase approach makes much more sense, since as you said, it would be impractical to read potentially billions of docs to validate against a few allowed documents.